# int value jumps from 0 to 32679 without change

Tags: c++, variables, loops, int

I have a really, really weird problem that I just can't figure out. So you can have a look, here is my code;

```
point * findLongPaths(point * points, double threshold_distance) {
    int i = 0;
    int pointsAboveThreshold = countPointsAboveThreshold(points, threshold_distance);

    point * pointsByThreshold = new point[sizeof(points)];
    pointValues * pointsToCalculate = new pointValues[pointsAboveThreshold];
    //pointValues pointsToCalculate[pointsAboveThreshold];
    //point orderedPoints[pointsAboveThreshold];

    while (points[i].end != true) {
        point pointOne = points[i];
        point pointTwo = points[i + 1];

        //Check to see if the distance is greater than the threshold, if it is store in an array of pointValues
        double distance = distanceBetweenTwoPoints(pointOne, pointTwo);
        if (distance > threshold_distance) {
            pointsToCalculate[i].originalLocation = i;
            pointsToCalculate[i].distance = distance;
            pointsToCalculate[i].final = pointTwo;

            //If the final point has been calculated, break the loop
            if (pointTwo.end == true) {
                pointsToCalculate[i].end = true;
                break;
            } else {
                pointsToCalculate[i].end = false;
                i++;
            }
        } else if (points[0].end == true || pointsAboveThreshold == 0) {
            //If there is no points above the threshold, return an empty point
            if (points[0].end == true) {
                point emptyPoint;
                emptyPoint.x = 0.0;
                emptyPoint.y = 0.0;
                emptyPoint.end = true;

                pointsByThreshold[0] = emptyPoint;
                return pointsByThreshold;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    //Find the point with the lowest distance
    int locationToStore = 0;

    while (pointsToCalculate[i].end != true) {
```

My problem is, the i value literally goes from 0 to 32679. I originally had it set to j, so it was using a different counter to the one in the while loop before but I tried it with the `i` to see if it would make a difference.

I have tried it in both VC++ and XCode and both are doing it. However, if I place a breakpoint a few lines before it, it stays as a zero. If I run it without any breakpoints, it changes the value to 32679.

Why is this? It's really weird and I have no idea how to fix it?

Comment: Where do you `i` go up? (i suppose `i++` just inside the while-loop) Where did you put your breakpoint? It just looks like you points array has 32680 entries without any `end`-value set to true.

Comment: Yeah, `i` is incremented in the while loop. I placed the breakpoint at the comment line `//Find the points with the lowest distance' and moved `i = 0` below the `int locationToStore = 0` line. Possibly, I will go have a look and see if I can find anything like that.

Comment: You are probably miscalculation the size of some array, and writing outside the allocated area. This for example `point * pointsByThreshold = new point[sizeof(points)];` allocates either  4 or 8 points depending on the size of a pointer. Probably not what was intended.

Comment: `//If the final point has been calculated, break the loop
            if (pointTwo.end == true) {
                pointsToCalculate[i].end = true;
                break;
            } else {
                pointsToCalculate[i].end = false;
                i++;
            }`

That there seems to break the loop and give the final value of `pointsToCalculate.end` to be `true`...

Comment: Ahhh.... Very true, @Bo_Persson. A way around it I guess would be to create a function that returns an int. The function will contain a loop and if a value for point exists, increment and return the incremented value when there are no more points? Then, I can create `pointsByThreshold` with the returned value? Do you think that might work?

Comment: "My variable doesn't change. Why is it changing?" Lol.

Comment: Who knows haha ;) It's working now though ;) Just need to fix up the algorithm and work on that for my submission.

Comment: Why delete all the code? Now anyone else who views the question cannot get help.

Answer (score 2):

A few things I noticed that may help:

- The `new point[sizeof(points)]` is almost certainly wrong as `sizeof(points)` does not equal the number of elements in the array but is the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8). If you want the size of `points[]` either pass it into the function as another parameter or, even better, use a standard container (like `std::vector<>` or whichever one fits your needs).
- Your `pointsToCalculate` array is allocated with `pointsAboveThreshold` elements but you then access it with `i`. If `i` ever exceeds `pointsAboveThreshold` (which almost certainly will) you will overflow the array and bad things will happen, possible including overwriting `i`. I would suspect this is your issue without more information and detail.
- When `distance > threshold_distance` and `pointTwo.end == false` you increment `i` twice (this may be intended but wanted to mention it in case).
- The `else if (points[0].end == true...)` can never be true as if it was the outer `while (points[i].end != true)` would be false and the loop never entered. I'm unsure of your intended logic but I would suspect you want this outside of the while loop.